# Scaling problems

Tags: wpf, windows-7, size, windows-10

My program works fine on my system, the problem is that my mate is using win7 and Iam using win10. The buttons and the whole window is adjusted on win7.

So I think to work with ClientSize but I don't have a real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF picks a default theme determined by the operating system version. This is so it's consistent with the user's experiece of the operating system. It's usually fine on most applications, but becomes a problem with more complex UX design.

If you want your system to look the same, you have to force-load a specific operating system theme.

Add this in your Application Startup event:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(“PresentationFramework.Aero;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml”, UriKind.Relative);

Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary);
```

Comment: Done, but VisualStudio redmarks "PresentationFramework" and V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\\themes/aero".

Comment: So solved the redmark problem, but it can't find the resource